# Poll REST API for long running task

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm designing a REST API to perform some tasks which require extensive computation, to be used by an additional service. In essence, a GET request to `/command` will begin the task, with the status being updated at `/queue/12345`. The client polls `/queue/12345/` until the task is complete, at which point the server sends a 303 with the location of the result (`/runs/12345`).

What I'm trying to do right now is to write the polling function on the client side. What I have right now can successfully poll - however, because the `setTimeout()` function is called immediately after the request is sent. This means that I will poll forever, even though I don't call `setTimeout()` in the callback function of the request.

**How can I ensure that my polling function ends once I've received a 303 status code?**

```
// standard first call is pollQueue(uri, 0);
function pollQueue(uri, timesPolled, callback) {
    if(timesPolled > 28800) {
        // 288800 is (60 sec/min * 60 min/hr * 24 hr) / 3 sec/poll. Aka 24 hours.
        throw 'ResourceWillNeverBeReady';
    }

    console.log("polling " + uri);
    request({
      url: "http://localhost:2500/" + uri,
      followRedirect: false
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if(response.statusCode === 303) {
            // callback handles requesting the actual data
            callback(response.headers.location); 
            return;
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() { pollQueue(uri, timesPolled + 1, callback);}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: i mean, yeah, that's what your code does. It sends the request, then ***without waiting for it to complete*** it starts the timer to send the next.

Comment: D'oh. Yes. I knew that was the problem but didn't connect the fact that I need to put the `setTimeout()` function in the callback.

Comment: also, this doesn't look like long polling, typically with long polling you send a request, then the server holds on to it for a period of time (10-30 seconds, maybe more) and only responds early if the value changes thus resulting in very little delay between updates on the ui compared to when they happened on the server.

Comment: Yup, it's not. In my actual application, tasks can take 1 minute to ~2-3 hours, depending on the command. So I was thinking of waiting ~30 seconds for each poll rather than the 3 I am right now. Do you think long polling would still be better in this context?

Comment: eh, it depends. is the user expected to keep this window open for 2-3 hours? an email notification might be more appropriate for something that can take that long.

Comment: I was thinking yes, but I hear your point. The client could potentially be an actual user, but more immediately it will be another web service, so that service could handle any email notifications.

Comment: Does the server/client know how long the task is going to run? or is that an unknown. I could see polling for shorter ones and skipping that process for ones you know will take longer.

Comment: Not exactly how long, but it can be approximated. I'll consider it moving forward - thanks for the help! Don't want to take more of your time.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that a webSocket connection can be very efficient for.  You create a webSocket connection to the server (I'd probably use the socket.io library myself) and then submit the job and the server sends the socket.io connection a message when the job is done.  No polling required.  It requires supporting webSocket/socket.io connections on the server and being able to correlate a given socket connection to the job ID so when the job is done, you know which socket to send the notification on.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin B pointed out the obvious. All I needed to do was move the `setTimeout()` function into the callback.

```
// standard first call is pollQueue(uri, 0);
function pollQueue(uri, timesPolled, callback) {
    if(timesPolled > 28800) {
        // 288800 is (60 sec/min * 60 min/hr * 24 hr) / 3 sec/poll. Aka 24 hours.
        throw 'ResourceWillNeverBeReady';
    }

    console.log("polling " + uri);
    request({
      url: "http://localhost:2500/" + uri,
      followRedirect: false
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if(response.statusCode === 303) {
            // callback handles requesting the actual data
            callback(response.headers.location); 
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(function() { pollQueue(uri, timesPolled + 1, callback);}, 3000);
    });
}
```